# Mass Spring System on Moon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

If we take a vertically hanging mass on a spring and move it to the moon where gravity is roughly 1/6 that of earth, but force it to oscillate at the same amplitude as it did on earth, what **doesn't** change?

The answer I was given was equilibrium position, but I'm curious as to why it wouldn't be another answer choice (this was a multiple choice question) - minimum kinetic energy.

To my understanding, kinetic energy is 1/2 mv^2. If v goes from positive to negative, as it must when the oscillation changes direction, per the intermediate value theorem, there must be a point where v = 0. If that's true, than KE at that point becomes 0. And since v is squared, that's the minimum possible value for it. This happens irregardless of what gravity is.

In addition, if I remember correctly, the equilibrium position is when kx = mg. Changing the amplitude shouldn't impact that, I believe.

So why does minimum kinetic energy change but equilibrium position stay the same?

Comment: Look at that as a driven oscillator. After a transient period, the oscillation is eventually driven entirely by the forcing oscillator. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscdr.html

Answer (score 1):

For a mass/spring simple harmonic oscillator the total energy is dependant only on the amplitude and the force constant of the spring$^1$. This is because at the maximum displacement, $d$, the mass is stationary so its kinetic energy is zero, and the potential energy in the spring is $\tfrac{1}{2}kd^2$. A corollary of this is that the maximum kinetic energy of the mass is also dependant only on the amplitude and the force constant of the spring. The minimum kinetic energy is trivially independent of everything because it is always zero.

Gert's comment raises the question of whether the phrasing:

> force it to oscillate at the same amplitude

means this is a forced harmonic oscillator. I would guess not, and it just means you pull the mass out to the same initial displacement before releasing it. In that case all the energies I mention above are the same on the Earth and the Moon.

However the equilibrium position will be different because it depends on the gravitational acceleration, as you say in your question.

---

$^1$ Taking the spring potential energy to be zero at the equilibrium displacement.